# Check if a `RECORD` variable is initialized

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm attempting to declare a variable with the data type `record` but am having troubles when there are no results to populate it with. Below is a simplified model of the function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        engagement record;
    BEGIN
        SELECT code
        INTO engagement
        FROM "mainEngagement" me
        WHERE me.value = NEW.id;

        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
        THEN
            INSERT INTO engagement_details (code)
            values (
                case
                    when engagement is not null
                        then exists(select code from engagement where "value" = 'expected')
                    else false
                end
            );
        ELSE
            UPDATE engagement_details
            SET
                code = case
                    when engagement is not null
                        then exists(select 1 from engagement where "value" = 'expected')
                    else false
                end
            WHERE engagement_details.assessment_id = NEW.id;
        END IF;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Updated engagement_details: [%]', NEW;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When the trigger runs and there is no data in "mainEngagement" I'm getting an error in the INSERT:

> ERROR: relation "engagement" does not exist

I cannot find a way to test if engagement is populated or not. I've searched through many stack overflow questions but most people just recommend doing `engagement := row(null)` but then `when engagement is not null` still doesn't work for me.

Comment: As you only select a single column of the table, you don't need a record variable to begin with. But the one you use, only has a single field: `code` (and no field named `"value"`) . But in any case you can not "select" from a record variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was having here was that a `RECORD` entry can only have one row as the result. I was attempting to return a value with multiple rows and then run the `CASE` statement over the record, which will never work. Instead do the following:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    DECLARE
        engagement boolean;
    BEGIN
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM engagement WHERE "value" = 'expected'
        ) INTO engagement;

        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
        THEN
            INSERT INTO engagement_details (code)
            values (engagement);
        ELSE
            UPDATE engagement_details
            SET
                code = engagement
            WHERE engagement_details.assessment_id = NEW.id;
        END IF;

        RAISE NOTICE 'Updated engagement_details: [%]', NEW;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Much simpler, cleaner, and works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IF NOT FOUND`:

```
SELECT code
INTO engagement
FROM "mainEngagement" me
WHERE me.value = NEW.id;

IF NOT FOUND
THEN
    RAISE WARNING '|W| do_something(): engagement undefined';    -- report warning
    RETURN;    -- exit early, function cannot proceed
END IF;
```

Comment: It being not found is valid though, and should just result in a default boolean value of `false` for the column in question.